# Why do some users that appear in Firebase StreamView appear with a "0" beside their name, whereas others have a "1"?

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

We have a potential issue where some users appear within the Firebase StreamView but are not counted as an active user within the 30 minutes that is shown.

Some users aren’t being counted as “active in the past 30 minutes” even though they have been on the app. In the StreamView it shows their name with a '0’ next to them, but isn’t including them within the number of people active in the past 30 minutes.

Are you still counted towards Daily Active Users (DAU) if you’ve been on the app, but (for a reason still unknown) you didn’t count towards the “Active in past 30 minutes” list even though you appeared on it with a “0” by your name?